# returning a list of strings separated by a delimiter

Tags: python, split

Im having some problems trying to solve this question. Its from a practice exam and I just can't seem to get it right. Im supposed to write a python function that takes in a string and a delimiter, and return a list back with the string stripped of the delimiter. We are not allowed to use the split function or "any such function". The example we received in the question was this

```
StringToken("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
```

Outputs

```
["this is so fun", "I love it"]
```

This is the code I made up, its super simple.

```
def tokenizer(string, tmp):
    newStr = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] != tmp:
            newStr.append(string[i])
    return newStr
```

and the output is this

`['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 's', 'o', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'n', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'i', 't']`

How can I rejoin each word?

Comment: Do you want to join the list or fix the problem of outputting individual characters?

Comment: I guess fix the problem of outputting individual characters. What I tried to do before asking this question was initializing newStr = ''. I would then do the same check and finally return [newStr]. This gave me the output of ['This is so fun I love it'] but as I can't use split. Im just stuck on how to get the desired output

Comment: Right, so you're needing to implement the split function without using split

Comment: @cricket_007 basically, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any tips?

Comment: You don't have to loop over all the characters. Please check my answer which uses `find` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you join all the elements in the list you will get a single string which may not be what you are looking for.

Create a string before append it to the list like;

```
>>> def StringToken(string, tmp):
    newStrlist = []
    newStr = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] != tmp:
            newStr += string[i]
        elif newStr != '':
            newStrlist.append(newStr)
            newStr = ''
    return newStrlist
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
>>> StringToken("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
['this is so fun', ' I love it']
```

Comment: Love it! This is what I was looking for. I knew I was missing something like this, but I'm surprised it was that simple. Can you explain why you set newStr = '' in the elif though? Thanks! Other then that it makes perfect sense !

Comment: otherwise after fist delimiter, new charecter will get appended with the first string. If you dont add have it, then the output will, `['this is so fun', 'this is so fun I love it']`.

Comment: ohh ok. So giving newStr = ' ' allows us to have the create the new placeholder for string[i] because if not then we would still have the first string! Makes total sense, had to think about it for a bit. Thanks for helping a newbie out :)

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the code for a description.

```
def StringToken(string, tmp):
    newStr = ""   # A string to build upon
    lst = []      # The list to return
    for c in string: # Iterate over the characters
        if tmp == c: # Check for the character to strip
            if newStr != "":   # Prevent empty strings in output
                lst.append(newStr.strip())   # add to the output list
                newStr = ""                  # restart the string
                continue                     # move to the next character
        newStr += c  # Build the string
    return lst   # Return the list
```

Output

```
StringToken("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
# ['this is so fun', 'I love it']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the all the letters in the string, you can use `find` to get the index of the next occurrence of the delimiter and then build your list accordingly:

```
def tokenizer(string, delim):
    new_list = []
    while True:
        index = string.find(delim)  # use find to next occurrence of delimiter
        if index > -1:
            new_list.append(string[:index])
            string = string[index + len(delim):]
        else:
            new_list.append(string)
            break              # break because there is no delimiter present anymore

    # remove whitespaces and trim the existing strings 
    return [item.strip() for item in new_list if item.strip()]
```

Usage:

```
>>> tokenizer("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
["this is so fun", "I love it"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that's a little shorter than the current answers:

```
def StringToken(string, tmp):
    newStr = []
    start = 0
    for ind, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == tmp:
            newStr.append(string[start:ind])
            start = ind + 1
    return newStr
```

Output

```
>>> StringToken("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
['this is so fun', ' I love it']
```

---

Edit: 
If you would like to remove leading or trailing spaces like in your example, that can be done using strip():

```
def StringToken(string, tmp):
    newStr = []
    start = 0
    for ind, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == tmp:
            newStr.append(string[start:ind].strip())
            start = ind + 1
    return newStr
```

Output

```
>>> StringToken("this is so fun! I love it!", "!")
['this is so fun', 'I love it']
```

Answer (score -1):

simply use join operator this will join entire list with a given delimiter.
Here in this you can use empty delimiter ''.
try:

```
a=['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 's', 'o', ' ', 'f', 'u', 'n', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'i', 't']
''.join(a)
```

output will be

```
'This is so fun I love it'
```